# Yesod - Form with foreign key

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I am developing my first application with Yesod and I am creating some CRUD api to start.

I have a model that looks like

```
User json
    ...

Activity json
    userId UserId
    ...
```

where `userId` is a foreign key.

I need to create an endpoint to be able to create a new Activity and the client needs to be able to specify the `userId`.

To do this I am using a form like

```
postCreateActivityR :: Hadler Value
postCreateActivityR = do
    activity <- runInputPost $ Activity
        <$> ...
        <*> ireq textField "userId"
    ...
```

Doing so I get an error like the following:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘Key User’ expected type: FormInput (HandlerT App IO) (Key User)
```

Is there a standard way to solve this?

Comment: I don't know anything from yesod, but I would try my chance with something like `optionsPersistKey` from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.4.15/docs/Yesod-Form-Fields.html#g:4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the records, this is how I solved it in the end

I had to create a new field

```
userIdField :: (Monad m, RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage) => Field m UserId
userIdField = Field
    { fieldParse = parseHelper $ \s ->
        case signed decimal s of
            Right (a, "") -> Right $ toSqlKey a
            _ -> Left $ MsgInvalidInteger s
    , fieldView = \_ _ _ _ _ -> ""
    , fieldEnctype = UrlEncoded
    }
```

and then use it like

```
<*> ireq userIdField "userId"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a SQL backend, there is `toSqlKey` in [Database.Persist.Sql](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.3/persistent-2.7.0/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:toSqlKey) module. Since you are given `Text`, you first need to convert it into `Int64` using [Data.Text.Read](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text-Read.html).